# Automating a Python script with Crontab

Tags: python, linux, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to automate a Python script on a Google Cloud VM using Crontab.

When I run `python Daily_visits.py` my code runs as expected and generates a table in BigQuery.

My Crontab job is as follows: `*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python Daily_visits.py` but generates no output.

I've run `which python` and I get `/usr/bin/python` back, and I have run `chmod +x Daily_visits.sh` on my file, what else am I missing?

Comment: if you run `crontab -l` do you visualise an entry regarding the cronjob you have just created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write absolute path for Daily_visits.py file. Go to Daily_visits.py file's directory and run command:

`pwd`

You take output like it:

`/var/www/Daily_visits.py`

Copy and paste it change into crontab.

`*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /var/www/Daily_visits.py`

Comment: Thank you @Mert - I tried this but I am still getting no results - all the files are in the same directory so I assumed I did not need the full path. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @BenP ok, what did you take output pwd command? Can you show me?

Comment: `pwd` returns `/home/bpowis` so I changed my job to `* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/bpowis/Daily_visits.py`

Comment: @BenP now, run this command -> /usr/bin/python /home/bpowis/Daily_visits.py and is it running?

Comment: @ Mert Yes this runs and generated the expected output.

Comment: @BenP If this running, crontab can run it. can you check crond status? for this, run this command -> `service crond status`if it is not running, run this command -> `service crond start`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167192/discussion-between-ben-p-and-mert-simsek).

Answer (score 1):

You should have written something like

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/Daily_visits.py
```

or you should have placed the script in the very same folder.

### UPDATE

The status of the `cron` service was stopped since you are working on a Google Cloud Shell and not on a proper virtual machine.

As @MertSimsek told you it was enough to start the cron service and then everything works as expected.

```
$ sudo service cron start
```

> Notice that since merely the [home of the user](https://cloud.google.com/shell/) is persistent all the change will be lost after you close it and open it again.

It is intended as a tool to run commands/small scripts not to develop and to be used as a normal virtual machine

> Cloud Shell instances are provisioned on a per-user, per-session basis. The instance persists while your Cloud Shell session is active and terminates after a hour of inactivity.